# Execute trigger after the workflow rules

Tags: trigger, workflow, field-update, after-trigger

We have many workflow rules on the account Object, one of it is it prevents the users from entering wrong data in to `Location__c`.I recently created a Trigger on the Account Object which looks for a field `Location__c` if it is changed I need the Trigger to be fired which makes a callout to POST this change to external system.

```
trigger updateLoccation Account (after update) {
 if(trigger.isupdate)
{
    set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();

    for( Id accountId : Trigger.newMap.keySet() ){
    System.debug('## Old Value of Location' +Trigger.oldMap.get(accountId).Location__c);
    System.debug('## New Value of Location' + Trigger.newMap.get(accountId).Location__c);
        if( (Trigger.oldMap.get(accountId).Location__c != Trigger.newMap.get(accountId).Location__c))
        {
            AccountIds.add(accountId); 
        }
    }
```

If in the UI I make the change  to `Location__c` on the Account Record say `NY to TN`, the trigger is fired and the callout is made to external system. Then the Workflow rules on the Account record is executed which basically checks if the Location assigned is right and  set it back to `NY`.Then again the trigger is fired but the old and new value of the field is `NY` so nothing happens. So the issue is two systems are out of sync, SF has 'NY' and External system has 'TN'. I need the external system know only when the changes happen on the field. Can anyone say why after the workflow field update I see the old and new value on the trigger same. How can I handle is this scenario any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't change the order Salesforce (see Order of Execution: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) executes triggers, flows, and workflow rules. You can only change their conditions, enable, or disable them. This is something you will need to work out with your team to decide. Why is there a workflow rule that reverses the location change?

Comment: @nbrown I get the order of execution but can you tell me why the new and old value in Trigger is not working when it is fired after the workflow field update is done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working-as-designed, [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm?search_text=order%20of%20execution) second-to-last bullet

> Exception.
>
> When a record is updated and subsequently triggers a workflow rule field update, Trigger.old in the last update trigger doesn’t contain the version of the object immediately before the workflow update, but the object before the initial update was made. For example, suppose that an existing record has a number field with an initial value of 1. A user updates this field to 10, and a workflow rule field update fires and increments it to 11. In the update trigger that fires after the workflow field update, the field value of the object obtained from Trigger.old is the original value of 1, rather than 10, as would typically be the case.

If you want the external system to stay in sync, you need either some form of state management within the transaction or to delegate the callout to async when the transaction has ended

Comment: [Change Data Capture](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture/understand-change-data-capture) and the [Replication API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/calls_for_data_replication.htm) are both options to consider as an alternative approach that occurs after the entire on platform transaction is complete.

Comment: @cropredy Here I am not using VF page instead I am making a future callout method from the trigger when the record is updated. Looks like Async Callout works with VF Pages. Do you think I could still use Async Callout for my usecase

Comment: Just use a future or queueqble to do the http callout

Comment: I am already using the future callout, using the future callout only I am seeing the behavior. I posted a different question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313523/making-callout-from-apex-triggers can you please help me with this