# Making Callout from Apex triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, callout, asynchronous

I have a Apex Trigger which makes the callout to the External system when a field in a record is updated. The Apex Trigger and the Callout method are like below

```
trigger updateLocation Account (after update) {
   List<String> jSONBody = new List<String>();
    
    if(trigger.isupdate)
    {
        set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();
        list<Account> acclist = new list<Account>();
        
        for( Id accountId : Trigger.newMap.keySet() ){
            if( (Trigger.oldMap.get(accountId).Location__c != Trigger.newMap.get(accountId).Location__c))
            {
                AccountIds.add(accountId); 
            }
        }
        
        if(AccountIds.size()>0)
        {
            acclist = [Select id,Location__c from Account WHERE Id IN: AccountIds ];
            
            for(Account acc : acclist)
            {
                        handleD365Request.updSubSegJSON js = new handleD365Request.updSubSegJSON();
                        js.Location= acc.Location__c;
                        jSONBody.add(json.serialize(js));
                        handleReq.handleAccountReqs(jSONBody,endPoint);
            }}
```

Apex Class with future method

```
  @future (callout=true)
    public static void handleAccountReqs(List<String> jsonBody,String endPoint) {
      ...............
        for (String str : jsonBody)
        {
        Http http1 = new Http();
        HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
        String d365EndPoint = resource + endPoint;           
        req1.setMethod('POST');
        req1.setTimeout(20000);
        req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+bearerToken);
        req1.setEndpoint(d365EndPoint);
        req1.setBody(str);
        req1.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        HttpResponse res1 = http1.send(req1);
       }
    }
```

The issue is we have workflow rules on the Accounts so when the update on the field happens the  Trigger is executed twice one from the record through through UI and other time when the workflow rules update the field. I am not here trying to restrict the trigger execute only once instead trying make call the external system when all the transaction is complete on the record.How can I make the callout  only when all the transaction is complete on the record. In the other question it was recommended to use the async callout , I read future callouts are async. I am not sure how I can handle the async callout out of the trigger or using the Continuation object as works with VF page I dont have a VF page here. Any help is greatly appreciated to handle this usecase.

Comment: @NickCook The problem is not having the trigger getting fired twice instead how to make the callout only when all the transaction on the record is complete.

Comment: Please dont close this question, I am not trying to ask how to restrict the trigger to execute only once. I want the external system to be called when all the transactions are done I mean the field update through UI& workflow rules are all done

Comment: Future occurs when transaction is DONE. If you pass Id of record, the future can requery to get latest state of the record

Comment: @cropredy Sorry I am not following you. In my code above the trigger fired twice and the before the Transaction is done. Do you say that I need to include the id field in my JSON that I compose and send to the future callout method?

Comment: The way triggers and workflow works, the system fires the trigger EACH time you make an update to the record, so it is firing TWICE, which IS your problem. I know you keep saying that your problem is the callout, but the trigger is just calling it each time it fires.
The real problem is that you're using a workflow to update the record. Use a before trigger or a Before Save Flow, and your trigger will fire only once.

Comment: Ah, if the record is being updated twice, you need state management (keep track of Id - or field in record) to avoid second callout

Comment: @cropredy Can you tell me how I can do the state management

Comment: @DavidSchach I guess the before update trigger will be an issue because what happens is if the field Location gets accidentally updated through the UI like A -> B the trigger gets fired  here old and new value map are not equal and callout is made to  external system it has the field value B. Within the same record the workflow rules executed and resets the field back to A again trigger gets fired but the callout is not made this time as the old and new value map are same now  'A'. Looking for a way that calls to the extrnal sys is made only aftr all the transactions are complete on the record

Comment: use static collections to keep track of recordIds that should only be delegated to an async method once

Comment: @cropredy Appreciate your help. Can you please explain me how I can use static collections to keep track of recordIds. I tried googling most of them were flows. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a class with a static collection to track Ids you don't want to do two callouts on.

```
public class TransactionState {
   static Set<Id> d365AccountIds = new Set<Id>();
   void addD365AccountId(Id acctId) {d365AccountIds.add(acctId);}
   Boolean isVisited(Id acctId) {return d365AccountIds.contains(acctId);}
}
```

and then reference in your trigger

```
trigger updateLocation Account (after update) {
  List<String> jSONBody = new List<String>();
  TransactionState ts = new TransactionState();

  Set<Id> d365SyncableAcctIds = new Set<Id>();
  for( Id accountId : Trigger.newMap.keySet() ){
     if(ts.isVisited(accountId)) {continue;} // have we done this acctId already?
     if(Trigger.oldMap.get(accountId).Location__c !=Trigger.newMap.get(accountId).Location__c) {
        d365SyncableAcctIds.add(accountId);
        ts.add(accountId);  // avoid doing twice
  }
   
   
        
  for(Account acc : [Select id,Location__c from Account WHERE Id IN: d365SyncableAcctIds ]) {
     handleD365Request.updSubSegJSON js = new handleD365Request.updSubSegJSON();
     js.Location= acc.Location__c;
     jSONBody.add(json.serialize(js));
     handleReq.handleAccountReqs(jSONBody,endPoint);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your question, I can think in 3 tries I would give to solve this issue:

1. [RECOMMENDED] try to avoid have the workflow and the trigger doing the same logic in the Account object. If both are looking for changes in the same field is better to concentrate all the logic in only one place (in the trigger in this case as you have some complex integration to do)
2. Set a new field on the Account object to be a flag for the trigger. Something like LastLocationSynced__c. Before calling the integration, check if this field is equal to the Location__c and, if not, fill this field with the Location__c value just after calling the integration.
3. If you have specific criteria in your workflow, just change the field "Evaluate the rule when a record is" of your workflow to "created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria". It should do the work.

Comment: The trigger and workflow doesnt do the same thing. The trigger gets executed when the Location is updated but we have workflow rule which runs in the background to see if wrong Location is set. I guess your solution is to make the trigger fire only once I guess but what I am looking for is to make the call out only when all the transaction are complete on the record

Comment: @user81642 have you looked at the order of execution?  as you'll see, the workflow fires after the trigger, so you'll need to do something.  Is there any reason you don't want to do any of these suggestions?